# Affine group and semidirect product

Tags: semidirect-product

I proved that $\mathrm{Aff}(n) \cong O(n) \rtimes \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathrm{Aff}(n) \cong \mathbb{R}^n \rtimes O(n)$, where $\mathrm{Aff}(n)$ is the affine group, $O(n)$ the orthogonal group, $\rtimes$ denotes the semi-direct product of two groups.

Does it make sense that $\mathrm{Aff}(n) \cong \mathbb{R}^n \rtimes O(n)$ holds? I saw that most sources tend write down $\mathrm{Aff}(n) \cong O(n)\rtimes \mathbb{R}^n$ and as a consequence I am not sure whether my proof of showing $\mathrm{Aff}(n) \cong \mathbb{R}^n \rtimes O(n)$ makes sense. I could give the proof if there is interest in that.

Comment: Where did you see $O(n)\rtimes \mathbb{R}^n$?  Are you sure it wasn't $O(n)\ltimes \mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: What is the difference between those expressions?

Comment: With $\rtimes$, the normal subgroup is on the left; with $\ltimes$, it is on the right.

Comment: I think it was $\ltimes$. But then why is $O(n) \rtimes \mathbb{R}^n \cong \mathrm{Aff}(n)$ not true? Both $O(n)$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ are normal subgroups right?

Comment: Because $O(n)$ is not a normal subgroup of $\mathrm{Aff}(n)$.

Comment: Yes I think I see what you mean. Thank you for clarification. I wrote $ghg^{-1} \in \mathrm{Aff}(n)$ with $g \in O(n)$ and $h \in \mathrm{Aff}(n)$ instead of $ghg^{-1} \in O(n)$ and $g \in \mathrm{Aff}(n)$ and $h \in O(n)$ for a normal subgroup...that was a sloppiness from my side.